# Excel Conditional Formatting Formula To Find Matching Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an array of numbers.  How do I use conditional formatting to highlight the cells that have the same value as the first cell in that column?  This is an example of what I want it to look like:

[image: Example of cells]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use formula like below.

```
=A2=A$1
```

See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I must have tried every combo but this one - THANKS!

Comment: @Alex If you found the answer useful then consider accepting the answer. Mark tick as green to accept it.